Embed the GStreamer RTSP video pipeline into a QT GUI
I'm currently working with a IP camera, which I need to display its video feed into a QT application. I have managed to create a Gstreamer pipeline that displays the feed properly with good latency. Here's the pipeline :
rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.144.25:8554/main.264 latency=100 ! queue ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! gtksink name=sink sync=false
I'm not sure which sink to use in the application, I'm trying to build, so for now I'm using gtksink, but I'm open to other suggestions.
I have built a very simple QT application with QT Designer that holds a play and pause button and a widget for the video feed:
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'mainwindow.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.10
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1057, 891)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 140, 89, 25))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 140, 89, 25))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.status_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.status_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 60, 111, 17))
        self.status_label.setObjectName("status_label")
        self.video_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.video_widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 240, 471, 311))
        self.video_widget.setObjectName("video_widget")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Start"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Stop"))
        self.status_label.setText(_translate("Form", "Pipeline Status"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

And the Python application itself:
import sys
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')  # Specify the Gtk version
from gi.repository import Gst, Gtk, GLib
from PyQt5.QtGui import QWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from mainwindow_ui import Ui_Form
import platform

# Initialize GStreamer
Gst.init(None)
Gtk.init()


class VideoPlayer(QMainWindow, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VideoPlayer, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pipeline = None
        self.video_window = None  # This will hold the window handle

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.start_pipeline)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.stop_pipeline)

    def start_pipeline(self):
        if not self.pipeline:
            # Create a DrawingArea for gtksink
            drawing_area = Gtk.DrawingArea()
            drawing_area.set_size_request(640, 480)  # Set size if needed

            GLib.timeout_add(500, drawing_area.realize)
            #drawing_area.realize()  # Ensure the widget is realized

            # Create the pipeline with an initial gtksink
            self.pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(
                f'rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.144.25:8554/main.264 latency=100 ! '
                f'queue ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! gtksink name=sink sync=false'
            )
                
             # Get the gtksink element 
            sink = self.pipeline.get_by_name("sink")

            # Connect to the 'realize' signal of the embedded widget
            widget = sink.get_property("widget")
            widget.connect("realize", self.on_widget_realized)


            # Start the pipeline
            self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

            self.status_label.setText("Pipeline Running")

    def on_widget_realized(self, widget):
        self.video_window = widget.get_window().get_xid()
        
        # Find the placeholder widget
        video_placeholder = self.findChild(QWidget, "video_widget")  

        # Create a QWindow from the window ID
        video_window = QWindow.fromWinId(self.video_window)

        # Create the window container and embed the QWindow
        container = QWidget.createWindowContainer(video_window, parent=video_placeholder)

        # Add the container to the video placeholder's layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout(video_placeholder)
        layout.addWidget(container)

    def stop_pipeline(self):
        if self.pipeline:
            # Stop the pipeline
            self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
            self.pipeline = None

            self.status_label.setText("Pipeline Stopped")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = VideoPlayer()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

Now it kind of works in the sense that it does display, but I have multiple issues. First, Gstreamer always opens its own GTK display window when I launch my app, and it seems it's linked to the embedded one too, since if I close it it closes the embedded one too. If I try to stop the feed and start it again with the buttons, it will relaunch in its own-pop up window, as described before, instead of in the QT UI window.
I'm open to any solutions, and what I want is a QR app  that display my video feed without any pop up window and can be stopped and started again without issues. Also, I will need to have multiple video feeds at the same time, all from a similar source (the same camera model).

I'm sharing the solution I use for rendering pipelines inside the Qt interface which consists in passing a window handle to the sink element (in this case any element that implements the GstVideoOverlay interface such as  glimagesink, xvimagesink, etc)
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton

import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('GstVideo', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst, GstVideo

class GUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pipeline_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.pipeline_widget.resize(500,500)
        self.push_button = QPushButton(self)
        self.push_button.setText(">||")
        self.push_button.pressed.connect(self.play_pause)
        self.playing = True
    
    def closeEvent(self, a0) -> None:
        global pipeline
        pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        super().closeEvent(a0)
        sys.exit()

    def play_pause(self):
        global pipeline
        if self.playing:
            pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PAUSED)
        else:
            pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

        self.playing = not self.playing


def main(args):
    global pipeline
    _ = QApplication(args)
    w = GUI()

    GObject.threads_init()
    Gst.init(None)

    pipeline_str = f'videotestsrc ! glimagesink name=sink'

    pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(pipeline_str)
    if not pipeline:
        sys.stderr.write('could not create pipeline\n')
        sys.exit(1)

    sink = pipeline.get_by_name('sink')

    win = w.pipeline_widget.winId() # retrieve the window handle
    sink.set_window_handle(win) # pass the handle to the sink

    loop = GObject.MainLoop()
    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    w.show()
    try:
        loop.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    # cleanup
    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
    sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)

This produces a window like the following

